# can we pass the user value in the Run Process command while the process is in execution

Tags: python, robotframework

I am running a process using robot framework, and the process prompts for user confirmation. Is there a way that I can pass the user value in the Run Process command while the process is in execution.

Example:

```
${result} = Run Process ${dir}/some_command shell=True
```

While the process is running, it asks for user confirmation like
"DIR does not exist.Do yo want to setup (yes/no)?"
i need to pass 'yes' for that.

Is there a way to do this?
If yes then can i pass the value in Run Process command itself?

Comment: `echo y |  del *` is an example

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an 'intelligent' way of doing this by latching on to your process/program. But you can always use the AutoIT library for robot framework. This library will allow you to code keyboard level input commands and allows a great deal of windows desktop automation. [Link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily doable with piping; if the prompt/input is just one - single variable:

```
${result} = Run Process  echo "${your_variable}" | ${dir}/some_command  shell=True
```